# Retrieve record ID after insert

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Admittedly, I am a bit out of my league here, but attempting this project anyway.

**Background:**

I am developing a page that will allow my users to enter data to a database.  The database has multiple tables that will have data inserted and updated.  The first action the user takes is to select an option from a drop down and click "create".  Clicking the create button will create a record in one of my tables.  Also, upon clicking "create" a larger form will be displayed.  Once the larger form is complete, the user can "save" their work.  I am planning on using an update query to allow the user to save their work.

**Question:**

I am using ajax to post the data (see example below), I essentially want to return the record ID (primary KEY) to the page so that when the visitor saves the additional information, the database knows what record to update.

//script

```
$(function(){
  $('#create').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();


    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "url",
       data: {"optimizationtype": $("#optimizationtype").val()},

       success: function(results){
        $("#mvt-experimentdetails").css("display", "inline-block");
        $("#create").attr('value', 'Save');
        $("#create").attr('id', 'save');


       }
     });

  });

});
```

//php includes

```
$expid = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

I know that I am suppose to return it in the success area of the ajax, but I am not sure exactly how to do that...Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP side, after you run the insert, you'll want to do the `last_insert_id` and echo that.

For example (using PDO and pseudocode):

```
insert into table values (x,y)
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
echo $id;
```

On the client side, let me recommend $.post instead of $.ajax - I find it much easier to use. However, the theory is the same for both.

```
$.post('url', {
        data-key: data-value,
        next-data-key: next-data-value
    }, 
    //now for the callback
    function (recordID) {
       //do something with recordID
        alert(recordID);
});
```

Comment: can I do something like this? `function (recordID){ $id = recordID }`?

Comment: That won't work, because `$id` is a PHP variable, which can only be edited on the server.